# Finding the derivative for this seemingly complicated function

Tags: partial-derivative, mathematica

I have the following equation -

$$I = \exp\left(\int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{-B-A|u(t)|^2}{AB}\ \mathrm{d}t_1\right)\cdot\left(1 + \int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{\exp\left(-\displaystyle\int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{-B-A|u(t)|^2}{AB}\ \mathrm{d}t_2\right)}{A}\ \mathrm{d}t_3\right).$$

where $u(t) = r(t) + i.m(t)$ with $i$ representing the usual $\sqrt{-1}$.

I am not sure if I am right in using $dt_1,dt_2,dt_3$ to represent the three different $dt$s, but I hope you understand what I am trying to say here.

I need to calculate the following partial derivatives of this function: $\frac{\partial I}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial I}{\partial m}$.

I obtained the expression of $I$ from Mathematica and this is correct. But I have no idea how to calculate the partial derivatives. Asking around on the Mathematica stackexchange site did not help. I am open to doing this calculation on pen-and-paper if required, but I am quite simply stuck. I am not sure how to apply the chain rule if I have to.

As an engineer, I guess what I am asking for is the easiest way for me to calculate the required derivatives. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: |u(t)|^2 = u(t) conjugate( u(t) ).  From here you can expand everything.  Then just use the product rule, the chain rule, and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Sorry, you have it written now so that $r(t)$ and $u(t)$ are function of $t$. So, they change over the region of integration. This seems like a functional derivative, since you can't differentiate them like their constants over the whole domain if they're functions of $t$. I t could just be my ignorance, but can you clarify what you mean by these partial derivatives?